# Delete part of an imported obj model in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I've made a model in Magicavoxel and exported it in obj format. I then import it to Blender to change pivot point. My problem is that i have to export it from Blender in two parts. My question is how do i delete a part of an obj import?

Comment: The same way you delete a part of any mesh. Which part of the workflow are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Ok thanks but i have almost no experience of Blender and have no clue yet how to delete anything the way i want to. But i'm going through tutorials from absolute scratch and i feel it will take some time until i reach the knowledge i need. I am in a bit of a hurry ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Is the meshed separated in group for OBJ file?

Try to use **Split by Group** in importing OBJ file:

[image]

In that way, the object can be imported separately if the OBJ use group for objects.

Just delete the object by <kbd>X</kbd>

### If the Object is still joined

Enter edit mode and deselect all vertices <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and hover on the main structure and press <kbd>L</kbd> for linked mesh. Revert your selected by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and delete those vertices.

Comment: Thanks! Both of these suggestions worked! I belive i have to stick with importing the parts seperatly to Blender to be able to keep the textures created in Magicavoxel. What do you think? Is there any way i can keep the textures of the part i am exporting from blender?